# How to hide roweditor cls from the editable record

Tags: javascript, extjs

How to hide roweditor cls.

I am using row ediotr in my extJS grid. When I am clicking to my editor it is showing in higlighted mannner.

Here is the image. I want to remove the grid higligting which happening on click of grid editor.

[image]

Here is my code to remove update and cancel button.

```
listeners:{
        'beforeedit':function(editor){
            editor.getEditor().floatingButtons.hide();
        } 
    },
```

Any help how to remove the hilighted cell which is my editor in extJS grid,

Comment: Use celledit instead rowedit: selType: 'cellmodel',
    plugins: {
        ptype: 'cellediting',
        clicksToEdit: 1
    },

Comment: @V.Tur I have to use to Rowedior therefore I m using row editor.

Comment: @V.Tur I want to hide floating dialog which appear.

Comment: It is a new component, therefore you might have to come up with a lot of work. But you could override the css. Here is a starting point for your buttons (hide) and the css: .x-grid-row-editor-buttons {display: none;}.x-grid-row-editor {}

Comment: @Dinkheller I am writing new plugin all together. well in this case where I need to apply the css.

Answer (score 0):

Just hide the RowEditingButtons on re-layout event:

```
listeners: {
    'beforeedit': {
        fn: function (editor) {
            editor.getEditor().on('afterlayout', function (editorComponent) {
                editorComponent.getFloatingButtons().hide();
            });
        },
        single: true
    }
}
```